# bcrypt ruby gem: problems after deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bcrypt

I followed this railscast and built a simple authentification architecture which works superb on development: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Now, after deploying to heroku I get an error when creating a new user.

Log:

```
2013-07-22T20:03:07.688326+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `password_salt=' for #<User:0x00000005ca3050>):
2013-07-22T20:03:07.792383+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:16:in `encrypt_password'
2013-07-22T20:03:07.898375+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

This method it is, in my user model:

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => "bcrypt"
```

bundle install ran successfully on heroku, the gem was installed

no clue what went wrong here, any ideas?

thanks

Comment: solved - gem version installed was 3.0.1, forced "~> 3.1.1" and works now!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `'rake db:migrate'` after deployment to the heroku server? **ActiveRecord** dynamically creates attributes in your model based on columns in tables. So most probably `users` table just doesn't have column `password_salt`.

Comment: sure, did that!
+ checking the user table via console tells me the column is there